# multiple kubernetes deployments using same global yaml as template

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have ran into an issue.
My goal: Create multiple nginx deployments using the same "template" file and use kustomize to replace the container name. This is just an example, as in the next steps I will add/replace/remove lines (for eg.: resources) from "nginx_temaplate.yml" for different deployments. For now I want to make the patches work to create multiple deployments :-) I am not even sure, if the structure is correct.

The structure is:

```
base/nginx_template.yml
base/kustomization.yml
base/apps/nginx1/nginx1.yml
base/apps/nginx2/nginx2.yml
```

**base/nginx_template.yml:**

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1 # tells deployment to run 1 pods matching the template
  template: # create pods using pod definition in this template
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: template
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: nginx
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

**base/kustomization.yml:**

```
resources:
  - nginx_template.yml

patches:
  - path: ./apps/nginx1/nginx1.yml
    target:
      kind: Deployment
  - path: ./apps/nginx2/nginx2.yml
    target:
      kind: Deployment
```

**base/apps/nginx1/nginx1.yml:**

```
- op: replace
  path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/name
  value: nginx-1
```

**base/apps/nginx2/nginx2.yml:**

```
- op: replace
  path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/name
  value: nginx-2
```

All it does now is, that it only creates the nginx-2. Thank you for any help.